# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: sorry, no mailbox here by that name (#5.1.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am developing web application in mvc5. I have email notifications to send it to our customers. I am using below details to send emails. I have hosted application with ssl mode. Port is 25, smtpServer is mail.ourdomain.com and email is alert@ourdomain.com. We use below code to send emails.

```
string AdminEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmail"].ToString();

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(emailid);
mail.Bcc.Add(AdminEmail);
mail.From = new MailAddress(MailID);
mail.Subject = Subject;
mail.Body = Body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(hostserver);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailID, Password);
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I found in the error log and there is `Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: sorry, no mailbox here by that name (#5.1.1)` May i know the root cause of this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: " May i know the root cause of this problem" ->> no mailbox here by that name

Comment: Hi Mitch. I get emails. But error occurs.

Comment: Do you get the e-mail at the to address and the bcc address?

Comment: Yes. I got the email.

Comment: Is the from address valid?

Comment: Yes. It is valid address

Comment: set a breakpoint on `smtp.Send(mail)`, and examine the values of `emailid`, `AdminEmail`, and `MailID`. Or hard-code the values for testing and see if the issue repros.

Comment: If you don't learn anything from Rufus' suggestion, you could manually telnet to the SMTP server and send the e-mail manually. If there's an issue there, then it's probably an issue outside of C#.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check. How can i manually telnet to SMTP server? I am getting emails but also getting error.

Comment: [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not created the object of MailAddress correctly.
Please see below way of creating mail address:

```
Message = new MailMessage();
Message.From = new MailAddress(UseremailId, "Your Application");
```

this will resolve the above issue.